# Sorting data with jQuery and Angular

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have a collection that I'm trying to sort by date.

Calling a **rest API** and returning **JSON** and using angular and **jquery** to display the records.

What is data-sort-by? Should this be the field name from the response?

```
[button class="b3 button btn" data-sort-by="date" (click)="sortByDate()"]By Date[/button]
```

This is the TypeScript.

```
sortByDate() {
    var $grid = this.getGrid();
    $grid.isotope({ sortBy: 'name', sortAscending: false }); // should sortBy be date?
}
```

Here is what the JSON response looks like.

```js
[{
  "Id": 1,
  "Name": "Test Event",
  "Date": "2018-09-05T00:00:00",
  "DisplayDate": "September 5-7, 2018 ",
  "DisplayTime": "All day event",
  "Location": "Orlando, FL",
  "Url": "http://google.com",
  "ContactName": "Joe Smith"
}]
```

Comment: is it necessary to use jquery in your angular app? what kind of sorting are you trying to do/by? whats this button data-sort-by attribute seems like folks are downvoting you because there's a lot of missing information in your question. it would help if you identified all frameworks/libraries in use.

Comment: Yes, it is an existing application that uses both of them combined. I wanted to sort the data. Yes, I know I'm missing information, I was hoping to find out the answers here. I have found the grid that is being used.

Answer (score 0):

After my research, I have found out it is a jQuery plugin for layout, sorting, etc.
I will read the documentation here. 
https://isotope.metafizzy.co/v1/docs/sorting.html#sortby_option